# Connecting AWS cloudfront with private azure blob storage

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on a project to upload files and then download it. I have tested the project using AWS S3 and delivering via AWS cloudfront. For performance reasons I intend to use azure blob for storing files too.

I am able to connect with azure blob through AWS cloudfront when my container access is public. I don't intend to keep my container access public.

does anybody know how to connect AWS cloudfront to azure blob storage when it is private.